# Eigenvalues of linear map of 3-tensors given by matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be a (symmetric) real $d\times d$- matrix. Consider the linear map

$$A : \mathbb{R}^{d\times d\times d} \to\mathbb{R}^{d\times d\times d}, K \mapsto AK,$$
given by

$$(AK)_{l,m,n} = \sum_{k=1}^ d M_{l,k} K_{k,m,n}.$$

Note, that if $M v = \lambda v$ and $N$ is any $d\times d$-matrix, then

$$A(v\otimes N)_{l,m,n} = \sum_{k=1}^ d M_{l,k} v_k N_{m,n} = (Mv)_l N_{m,n} = \lambda v_l N_{m,n} = \lambda (v \otimes N)_{l,m,n}.$$

Here, $v\otimes N \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d\times d}$ with $(v\otimes N)_{m,n,l} := v_m N_{m,l}$. Thus, we have $\sigma(M)\subseteq \sigma(A)$, where $\sigma$ denotes the spectrum of a matrix or linear map.

Can we show that $\sigma(M) =\sigma(A)$ or are there counterexamples? If there are, can we bound the spectral radius $r_A$ of $A$ using a function of $r_M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you identify each $K\in\mathbb R^{d\times d\times d}$ with an augmented matrix $K'=\pmatrix{K_1'&K_2'&\cdots&K_d'}\in\mathbb R^{d\times d^2}$ so that $K_{l,m,n}=(K_n')_{l,m}$, then $AK$ is simply represented by the matrix $MK'$ in $\mathbb R^{d\times d^2}$. It follows that the spectrum of $A$ (as a multiset) is precisely the union of $d^2$ copies of the spectrum of $M$.

Put it another way, let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_d\}$ be an eigenbasis of $M$ and $Mv_j=\lambda_jv_j$ for each $j$. Denote the $i$-th element of $v_j$ by $v_{ij}$. For each $(j,m',n')\in\{1,2,\ldots,d\}^3$, define $K^{(j,m',n')}\in\mathbb R^{d\times d\times d}$ by $K_{l,m,n}^{(j,m',n')}=\delta_{m,m'}\delta_{n,n'}v_{l,j}$. Then each $K^{(j,m',n')}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_j$ and $\{K^{(j,m',n')}:(j,m',n')\in\{1,2,\ldots,d\}^3\}$ is an eigenbasis of $A$. Therefore the spectrum of $A$ is the union of $d^2$ copies of the spectrum of $M$.

Comment: Ah, and then I suppose you are using the fact that, counting multiplicities, $A$ has at most $d^3$ eigenvalues, so there aren't any additional eigenvalues. That was easier than I expected. Thanks! EDIT: Or just the fact that those are enough linearly independent eigenvectors. I get it now.